# Installation - Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: visual-studio, installation, failed-installation

am having problems on trying to install Microsoft Visual Studio RC 2017. Whenever I try and install the program, mid-way through, the program says:

> "The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due
>   to one or more package failures."

Is there anyway I can fix this problem or go around it? I cannot simply install Visual Studio. The lists of commands that were returned are below. How do I fix this? I've already tried uninstalling everything and I can't seem to figure anything

```
The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures.

Incomplete workloads
    .NET Core cross-platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools,version=15.0.26127.0)
    .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.0.26127.0)
    ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26127.0)
    Azure development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure,version=15.0.26109.1)
    Data storage and processing (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data,version=15.0.26127.0)
    Desktop development with C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop,version=15.0.26109.1)
    Game development with C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeGame,version=15.0.26127.0)
    Mobile development with .NET (Preview) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26127.3)
    Mobile development with JavaScript (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebCrossPlat,version=15.0.26109.1)
    Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26109.1)
    Visual Studio extension development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VisualStudioExtension,version=15.0.26109.1)

Incomplete components
    .NET Core runtime (Microsoft.Component.NetFX.Core.Runtime,version=15.0.26109.1)
    .NET desktop development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26109.1)
    .NET Portable Library targeting pack (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.PortableLibrary,version=15.0.26109.1)
    ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26127.0)
    Azure Cloud Services core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Waverton,version=15.0.26109.1)
    Azure Cloud Services tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.CloudServices,version=15.0.26004.1)
    Azure Data Lake Tools (Microsoft.Component.Azure.DataLake.Tools,version=15.0.26109.1)
    Azure development prerequisites (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26109.1)
    Azure Resource Manager core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.26109.1)
    Azure Resource Manager tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.26109.1)
    Data sources for SQL Server support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources,version=15.0.26004.1)
    Managed Desktop Workload Core (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=15.0.26109.1)
    Redgate SQL Search (Component.Redgate.SQLSearch,version=15.0.26127.0)
    SQL Server Data Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,version=15.0.26109.1)
    Universal Windows Platform tools (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26127.0)
    Universal Windows Platform tools for Cordova (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.0.26109.1)
    Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.0.26109.1)
    Visual Studio extension development prerequisites (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.VisualStudioExtension.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26004.1)
    Windows 10 SDK (10.0.14393.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393,version=15.0.26127.0)

You can search for solutions using the information below, modify your selections for the above workloads and components and retry the installation, or remove the product from your machine.

Following is a collection of individual package failures that led to the incomplete workloads and components above. To search for existing reports of these specific problems, please copy and paste the URL from each package failure into a web browser. If the issue has already been reported, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, you can create a new issue where other people will be able to find solutions or workarounds.

Package 'Microsoft.PortableLibrary.TargetingPack.Msi.Resources,version=15.0.26109.1,language=en-US' failed to install.
    Search URL: aka(DOT - Need 10 Reputations)ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.PortableLibrary.TargetingPack.Msi.Resources;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1714
    Impacted workloads
        .NET Core cross-platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools,version=15.0.26127.0)
        .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.0.26127.0)
        ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26127.0)
        Azure development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Data storage and processing (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data,version=15.0.26127.0)
        Mobile development with .NET (Preview) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26127.3)
        Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Visual Studio extension development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VisualStudioExtension,version=15.0.26109.1)
    Impacted components
        .NET desktop development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26109.1)
        .NET Portable Library targeting pack (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.PortableLibrary,version=15.0.26109.1)
        ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26127.0)
        Azure Cloud Services core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Waverton,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Azure Cloud Services tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.CloudServices,version=15.0.26004.1)
        Azure Data Lake Tools (Microsoft.Component.Azure.DataLake.Tools,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Azure development prerequisites (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Azure Resource Manager core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Azure Resource Manager tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Data sources for SQL Server support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources,version=15.0.26004.1)
        Managed Desktop Workload Core (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Redgate SQL Search (Component.Redgate.SQLSearch,version=15.0.26127.0)
        SQL Server Data Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Universal Windows Platform tools (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26127.0)
        Visual Studio extension development prerequisites (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.VisualStudioExtension.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26004.1)
    Log
        C:\Users\Vishwadeep Singh.VishwadeepSingh\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170201205921_131_Microsoft.PortableLibrary.TargetingPack.Msi.Resources.log
    Details
        MSI: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.PortableLibrary.TargetingPack.Msi.Resources,version=15.0.26109.1,language=en-US\portablelibrary_dtplp_sfx.msi, Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1  MSIFASTINSTALL="7"  VSEXTUI="1"  EXTUI="1" 
        Return code: 1714
        Return code details: The older version of Microsoft Portable Library Multi-Targeting Pack Language Pack - enu cannot be removed.  Contact your technical support group.  

Package 'Microsoft.Net.CoreSDK.50,version=1.0.23907' failed to install.
    Search URL: aka(DOT - Need 10 Reputations)ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.Net.CoreSDK.50;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1714
    Impacted workloads
        .NET Core cross-platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools,version=15.0.26127.0)
        .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.0.26127.0)
        ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26127.0)
        Azure development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Data storage and processing (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data,version=15.0.26127.0)
        Mobile development with .NET (Preview) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26127.3)
        Mobile development with JavaScript (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebCrossPlat,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Visual Studio extension development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VisualStudioExtension,version=15.0.26109.1)
    Impacted components
        .NET Core runtime (Microsoft.Component.NetFX.Core.Runtime,version=15.0.26109.1)
        .NET desktop development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26109.1)
        .NET Portable Library targeting pack (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.PortableLibrary,version=15.0.26109.1)
        ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26127.0)
        Azure Cloud Services core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Waverton,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Azure Cloud Services tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.CloudServices,version=15.0.26004.1)
        Azure Data Lake Tools (Microsoft.Component.Azure.DataLake.Tools,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Azure development prerequisites (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Azure Resource Manager core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Azure Resource Manager tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Data sources for SQL Server support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources,version=15.0.26004.1)
        Managed Desktop Workload Core (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Redgate SQL Search (Component.Redgate.SQLSearch,version=15.0.26127.0)
        SQL Server Data Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Universal Windows Platform tools (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26127.0)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Cordova (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Visual Studio extension development prerequisites (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.VisualStudioExtension.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26004.1)
    Log
        C:\Users\Vishwadeep Singh.VishwadeepSingh\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170201205921_132_Microsoft.Net.CoreSDK.50.log
    Details
        MSI: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.CoreSDK.50,version=1.0.23907\netfx_NETCoreSDK.msi, Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1  MSIFASTINSTALL="7" 
        Return code: 1714
        Return code details: The older version of Microsoft NetStandard SDK cannot be removed.  Contact your technical support group.  

Package 'Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795,version=10.0.14393.79500' failed to install.
    Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=-2147023293
    Impacted workloads
        Desktop development with C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Game development with C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeGame,version=15.0.26127.0)
        Mobile development with .NET (Preview) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26127.3)
        Mobile development with JavaScript (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebCrossPlat,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26109.1)
    Impacted components
        Universal Windows Platform tools (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26127.0)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Cordova (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.0.26109.1)
        Windows 10 SDK (10.0.14393.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393,version=15.0.26127.0)
    Log
        C:\Users\Vishwadeep Singh.VishwadeepSingh\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170201205921_164_Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795.log
    Details
        Command executed: "c:\windows\syswow64\\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -InputFormat None -Command "& """C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795,version=10.0.14393.79500\WinSdkInstall.ps1""" -SetupExe sdksetup.exe -SetupLogFolder standalonesdk -PackageId Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795 -LogFile """C:\Users\Vishwadeep Singh.VishwadeepSingh\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170201205921_164_Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795.log""" -SetupParameters """/features OptionId.WindowsSoftwareDevelopmentKit OptionId.WindowsSoftwareLogoToolkit OptionId.NetFxSoftwareDevelopmentKit /quiet /norestart"""; exit $LastExitCode"
        Return code: -2147023293
        Return code details: Fatal error during installation.
```

Comment: Go to Control Panel—Programs and Features, right click ‘Microsoft Visual Studio 2017’ and choose ‘Uninstall’, then delete the installation folders: %ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages and %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017. Reboot the computer and download the troubleshooter tool: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed to run it. Re-run the VS 2017 installer as administrator to install.

Comment: Meanwhile, before the next new installation, make sure windows update is up-to-date, temporarily disable antivirus software, clean up the %temp% folder and re-run the VS 2017 as administrator . If the installation still failed, use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder, upload it to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT I had similar problems with VS 2017 and your instructions didn't work. This is driving people nuts. My Windows 10 is up to date.

Comment: @MosesMachua, could you please share your installation logs like I said before?

Comment: @Sara-MSFT Here's a dropbox link. My OneDrive is full :( https://www.dropbox.com/s/jgpwvnk6jqh9v1c/vslogs.zip?dl=0

Comment: @MosesMachua, I found a error information in the log: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional /log C:\Users\Moses Machua\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170309201830_251_Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK.log /quiet /norestart, Return code: -2147023274, Details: Error opening installation log file. Verify that the specified log file location exists and that you can write to it. You can right click the specified log file and the folder %temp% to check the security tab, confirm your account have the full permission, run the installer as administrator and disable antivirus software.

Answer (score 1):

This is still a problem with the RTM installer. These lines give you the relevant information:

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.PortableLibrary.TargetingPack.Msi.Resources,version=15.0.26109.1,language=en-US\portablelibrary_dtplp_sfx.msi, Properties: REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1 MSIFASTINSTALL="7" VSEXTUI="1" EXTUI="1"
>
> Return code: 1714
>
> Return code details: The older version of Microsoft Portable Library Multi-Targeting Pack Language Pack - enu cannot be removed. Contact your technical support group

and

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.CoreSDK.50,version=1.0.23907\netfx_NETCoreSDK.msi, Properties: REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1 MSIFASTINSTALL="7"
>
> Return code: 1714
>
> Return code details: The older version of Microsoft NetStandard SDK cannot be removed. Contact your technical support group.

There are a variety of reasons why this might be the case but the most common one I would suspect is having removed the relevant MSIs, perhaps to free up disk space with something like CCleaner.

The easiest way to get past this is the Windows Installer Clean Up tool - which Microsoft, in their infinite wisdom, have decided to no longer distribute (because 'format and reinstall' is a much better solution to everything). Fortunately there are still mirrors out there such as via MajorGeeks:

http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/windows_installer_cleanup_utility.html

Install and run the tool to get a list of all the packages registered with Windows Installer, like so:

[image]

Select the packages which are preventing your VS install from proceeding and Remove. Now you are free to try installing again and see what other problems you get next.

When you're done, don't forget to thank Microsoft for fining innovative new ways to make developers' lives more difficult:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, was starting to lose patients with this install!